# How do I model-check a module that depends on an unbound variable?

Tags: tla+

I'm going through *Specifying Systems* right now and I'm a little puzzled about how I'd model-check the following module:

```
---------------------------- MODULE BoundedFIFO ----------------------------
EXTENDS Naturals, Sequences
VARIABLES in, out
CONSTANT Message, N
ASSUME (N \in Nat) /\ (N > 0)

Inner(q) == INSTANCE InnerFIFO

BNext(q) == /\ Inner(q)!Next
            /\ Inner(q)!BufRcv => (Len(q) < N)

Spec == \EE q : Inner(q)!Init /\ [][BNext(q)]_<<in, out, q>>
=============================================================================
```

I see that both the `Init` and `BNext` formulas are operators, parameterized by `q`. How would I supply this to the model checker?

Comment: I think it's \EE, not \E, since it's the temporal quantifier.

Comment: @Hovercouch thanks, made that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: `\E x : P(x)` is an unbounded expression, which TLC cannot handle. Many of the specs in *Specifying Systems* can't be modeled. More recent guides, such as the *TLA+ Hyperbook* or *Learn TLA+*, are more careful to keep all of their specs modelable.